# i want to retrieve data from mongo db but TypeError : 'NoneType' keeps coming

Tags: python, discord

here is code

```py
@client.command(aliases=['bal'])
async def balance(ctx):
    data=await client.eco.find(ctx.author.id)
    if ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_guild:
        bal=data["balance"]
        e=discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s Balance",description=bal,color=ctx.author.color)
        e.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
        await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

I want to find the data from mongo db and send it. when I run the command it says
( Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable )

I first tried to find the user's data in db and then if it exists, find user's balance and send it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `data=await client.eco.find(ctx.author.id)` is returning `None`. Just print the `data` variable to check. Usually this error comes when you use operator [] on variable whose value is None.
The `find` method can be used to find a single document matching your query or return `None`.